# For a while or in a while

Tags: grammaticality

Ok so... My friend and i used to walked to school sometimes but we haven't done that recently.
I messaged him " we haven't walked in a while "
He replied " for a while* "
And now we're arguing over it.
Which is correct? 
Thanks

Comment: The correct thing to do is get better friends who don't message you to correct your diction.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard both, but I believe "in a while" is more commonly used in this case.

"... in a while" would be used more for things that are not actively occurring, to denote the time since it last happened or until it will happen again.

"... for a while" would indicate how long something happened or has been happening.

Think of how "a little while" would be used in the same example.  "I will walk in a little while" would mean that I'm not walking now, but will relatively soon.  "I will walk for a little while" would mean that I'll start walking (probably soon) but I won't walk for a long amount of time.